# Something like JW Player but free?

Tags: html, jwplayer, flv

Anyone knows of a player like JW Player, that can be easily embedded to sites to reproduce .flv files, but free? The free version of JW Player has the text 'jwplayer' in the middle of the video, which is not good. Any free options?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, the text "jwplayer" is only visible in the first few seconds.

But perhaps http://flv-player.net/ might be an alternative.

Answer (score 1):

As I know, the JW Player logo does not go away until you purchase a Pro version from them. Correct me if i'm wrong.